# Как востановить таблицу, если REPAIR TABLE не помогает?

Tags: php, sql

Привет Всем! Разрушалась таблица files. Проблема в том что там важные данные, но починка таблицы REPAIR TABLE `xbtit_files` - не срабатывает.

```
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55359...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55365...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55392...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55470...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found link that points at -7291133382739577391 (ou...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  error   Not enough memory for blob at 555116 (need 2135856...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55359...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55365...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55392...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found block that points outside data file at 55470...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  info    Found link that points at -7291133382739577391 (ou...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  error   Not enough memory for blob at 555116 (need 2135856...
xbtit.xbtit_files   repair  status  Operation failed
```

Я так понял памяти не хватает, а как её добавить и куда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй Navicat, я им много "неподнимаемых" баз поднимал)

ЗЫ: софтина под винду

ЗЫЫ: первым делом, первым делом - всё бекапить! а настраивать - настраивать потом!©башорг

И если есть важные данные - бекапы и UPS! Обязательно!:)

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Здесь есть решение!
http://subreal-team.com/blog/2013/09/05/mysql-what-do-if-not-help-repair-table-and-myisamchk/

Answer (score 1):

Нужно временно увеличить лимиты в /etc/my.cnf
например:

```
interactive_timeout = 9860
wait_timeout = 9860
connect_timeout =9820
```

- перезапустите mysql остановите nginx/httpd
- выполните repair из коммандной строки
- верните лимиты, перезапустите  mysql и запустите nginx/httpd